# Difference between DATE(time_field) AND time_field in a WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have 3 tables:

```
users
movements
unique_ids
```

I want to get the records gotten from march until now of the users registered in march, counting the unique id of their movements with a distinct and the total of it at the end:

```
SELECT MONTH(mo.ctime) AS month, COUNT(DISTINCT(unique_id))
FROM users us, movements mo,unique_ids id
WHERE us.time_field > '2014-03-01' AND us.time_field < '2014-03-31 23:59:59'
AND mo.time_field > '2014-03-01'
AND us.room_name LIKE 'name'
AND us.room_name=mo.room_name AND us.user=mo.user AND id.id_log=mo.id_log
GROUP BY month WITH ROLLUP
```

The thing is that few month ago in other query I realise that adding **DATE()** to the time_field into WHERE clause makes faster the query, but adding this into the query shown, gives me different results than the initial one.

What's the difference between **time_field > 'x'** AND **DATE(time_field) > 'x'** inside **WHERE clause**?

Comment: Could it be a time zone issue? TIMESTAMPs has them, DATEs do not.

Comment: how could the time zone makes this both queries results  to be different?

Comment: Clients in different timezones? It's just a first thought which is why I commented and didn't answer. Look (here) at FROM_UNIXTIME and compare your fields as a first guess - if you're getting different results, there must be a difference in the data somewhere.

Comment: mmm ok, if I understood well, all data is located in the same server, so all must have the same timezone

Comment: Ooops - sorry. It could be that DATE() removes the time and removes/changes/truncates any time field to a default - i.e. midday (or whatever). I can't test as I don't have a running MySQL server at the minute - am installing as we speak. Check it out for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just addressing this question

> What's the difference between time_field > 'x' AND DATE(time_field) > 'x' inside WHERE clause?

The difference is how the Query Optimizer treats them.

- If the `WHERE` clause has `time_field > 'x'`, this signals the Query Optimizer to try looking for any index so as to take advantage of it doing a range scan.
- If the `WHERE` clause has `DATE(time_field) > 'x'`, this signals the Query Optimizer to [throw all indexes under the bus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Throw_under_the_bus) because the [**DATE function**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) has to be called across the whole table (in the form of a full table scan) or the join result.

Depending on the key distribution of `time_field`, `DATE(time_field) > 'x'` triggering a full table scan just happens to be better than a range scan on an index if the values make up a significant percentage of the index. This is even more true using InnoDB because a full table scan passes through the clustered index (where `PRIMARY KEY` and row data coexist), while a secondary index on `time_field` would cause a lookup of the secondary index  in addition to the clustered index. If such a secondary index had a lopsided key distribution, such an index would be ignored in favor of a full table scan anyway.

This conjuecture is only indicative of your current dataset. Someone else's dataset may have a better (evenly distributed, more balanced) key distribution, resulting in `time_field > 'x'` working better than `DATE(time_field) > 'x'`.

To see such differences, run the `EXPLAIN` on both `SELECT` queries. The results may be different.

Comment: Excellent answer as always. Thank you very much.